# XMLHttpRequest leak

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, firebug, xmlhttprequest

Below is my javascript code snippet. Its not running as expected, please help me with this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   function getCurrentLocation() {
     console.log("inside location");
     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
       insert_coord(new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude)); 
       });
   }

   function insert_coord(loc) {
     var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
     request.open("POST","start.php",true);
     request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                                     callback(request);
                                  };
     request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
     request.send("lat=" + encodeURIComponent(loc.lat()) + "&lng=" + encodeURIComponent(loc.lng()));

     return request;
   }

   function callback(req) {
     console.log("inside callback");
     if(req.readyState == 4)
       if(req.status == 200) {
         document.getElementById("scratch").innerHTML = "callback success";
         //window.setTimeout("getCurrentLocation()",5000);
         setTimeout(getCurrentLocation,5000);
       }
   }

getCurrentLocation(); //called on body load
</script>
```

What i'm trying to achieve is to send my current location to the php page every 5 seconds or so. i can see few of the coordinates in my database but after sometime it gets weird. Firebug show very weird logs like simultaneous POST's at irregular intervals.

Here's the firebug screenshot: [image: firebug screenshot]

IS there a leak in the program. please help.

EDIT: The expected outcome in the firebug console should be like this :-

> inside location
>   POST ....
>   inside callback
>
> /* 5 secs later */
>
> inside location
>   POST ...
>   inside callback
>
> /* keep repeating */

Comment: Look here:  http://jsfiddle.net/ayLs7/  It reproduces your question without the calls to your specific AJAX page.  I have not seen it produce the issue you've described, even after letting it run for awhile.  I suspect the issue is not with the XHR, but may be in some other area of your Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the problem, but I can suggest two refactorings:

Merge your two conditions in callback():

```
if ((req.readyState == 4) && (req.status == 200)) {
```

And you can shorten your setTimeout line to:

```
setTimeout(getCurrentLocation, 5000);
```

And in an effort to fix the problem, can I get you to remove the setTimeout() from callback(), and replace the call to getCurrentLocation() with it? So you're only writing "callback success" when the callback is run, nothing else.

```
setTimeout(getCurrentLocation, 5000); //called on body load
```

Comment: i made the changes you mentioned. also i need the setTimeout inside callback because i want the code to be running every 5 seconds in a loop forever. The behaviour is still not as expected. Like its shown in the firebug screenshot, sometimes the post's appear in an instant and sometimes they don't appear at all. I want to make the POST's every 5 seconds.